# Private nuget repositroy deleting extra copied nupkg file in outputDIrectory

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore, nuget-server

I'm having a private nuget repository.  From this reposiory i'm downloading and extracting the nupkg using the below command

```
nuget install testspec -Source <url> -Exclude -OutputDirectory "c:\temp"
```

So it create a folder call testspec inside c:\temp and extract the content of nupkg inside that.

But i get the copy of the package also present in the same folder after extraction. What I mean to say, c:\temp\testspec I'm able to find testspec.nupkg.

How do i avoid copying the nupkg file or a copy here? Is there any flag i can set during the installation of nuget command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `-PackageSaveMode` flag in the install command. package save mode flag allows you to select if you want to save the package nuspec, nupkg or both. You can read more about it `[here][1]`.

In your case you can pass `-PackageSaveMode nuspec` and that will prevent the nupkg from being saved onto the disk.E.g. -

```
nuget install testspec -Source <url> -Exclude -OutputDirectory "c:\temp" -PackageSaveMode nuspec
```